# T-SQL script produces wrong calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The script below has an issue when it encounter division or averages etc. I would like to produce a result in the screen shot below but there is an "N/A" value in the column which messes up the counts, sums, averages etc. If I exclude the count of N/A then it returns zero 0 which messes up the averages. It incorrectly calculates as there should be 17 rows and and there are 7 5's in the result set as you can see from the Calculations arrow so the division of 7/17 which should be equal to 0.411764 but it's 0.388889. Any ideas?

```
   Create Table Test
(
    Q4 NVARCHAR(255),
    Q5 NVARCHAR(255)
);
 
INSERT  INTO Test
(
    Q4,
    Q5
)
VALUES  ('Strongly Agree', 'Agree'),
        ('Neutral', 'Disagree'),
        ('Neutral', 'Agree'),
        ('Strongly Agree', 'Disagree'),
        ('Agree', 'Strongly Disagree'),
        ('Strongly Disagree', 'Agree'),
        ('Strongly Agree', 'Disagree'),
          ('Agree', 'N/A'), -- Calculation Issue here because of N/A
        ('Agree', 'Strongly Disagree');
 
 
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn,
CASE WHEN [Q4] = 'Strongly Agree' THEN 5
WHEN [Q4] = 'Agree' THEN 4
WHEN [Q4] = 'Neutral' THEN 3
WHEN [Q4] = 'Disagree' THEN 2
WHEN [Q4] = 'Strongly Disagree' THEN 1
--WHEN [Q4] = 'N/A' THEN NULL
--when nullif([Q4], 'N/A') IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
END AS TestQ4,
CASE WHEN [Q5] = 'Strongly Agree' THEN 5
WHEN [Q5] = 'Agree' THEN 4
WHEN [Q5] = 'Neutral' THEN 3
WHEN [Q5] = 'Disagree' THEN 2
WHEN [Q5] = 'Strongly Disagree' THEN 1
END AS TestQ5
 
FROM  Test
--where [Q4] <> 'N/A'
),
RolledUp AS (
    SELECT
      rn,    
         TestQ4, -- Question 4
         TestQ5, -- Question 5
 
       grouping = GROUPING(TestQ4),
      count = COUNT(*),
      count2 = COUNT(TestQ4),
   
        -- Question 4 as TestQ4
         sum4 = SUM(TestQ4),
      avg4 = AVG(TestQ4 * 1.0),
      one4 = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 1 THEN 1 END),
     
       onePct4 = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 1 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
       CountFourOf_Two = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 2 THEN 1 END),
       onePct4CountFourOf_Two = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 2 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
       CountFourOfThree = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 3 THEN 1 END),
       onePct4CountFourOfThree = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 3 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
         CountFourOfFour = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 4 THEN 1 END),
       onePct4CountFourOfFour = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 4 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
     
       CountFourOfFive = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 5 THEN 1 END),
       onePct4CountFourOfFive = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 5 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),


 -- Question 5 as TestQ5
      sum5 = SUM(TestQ5),
      avg5 = AVG(TestQ5 * 1.0),
      one5 = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 1 THEN 1 END),
      
       onePct5 = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 1 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
       CountFiveOf_Two = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 2 THEN 1 END),
       onePct5CountFiveOf_Two = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 2 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
 
       CountFiveOfThree = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 3 THEN 1 END),
       onePct5CountFiveOfThree = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 3 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
 
         CountFiveOfFour = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 4 THEN 1 END),
       onePct5CountFiveOfFour = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 4 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
      
       CountFiveOfFive = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ5 = 5 THEN 1 END),
       onePct5CountFiveOfFive = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 5 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
     
 
    FROM cte1
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
        (rn, TestQ4, TestQ5),
        ()
    )
)
SELECT  v.TestQ4, v.TestQ5
FROM RolledUp r
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TestQ4,TestQ5,  0 AS ordering
    WHERE grouping = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value1,value2, ordering
    FROM (VALUES
        (NULL,NULL, 1),
        (count2,COUNT,  2),
        (sum4,sum5, 3),
        (avg4,avg5, 4),
        (one4,one5, 5),
        (onePct4,onePct5, 6),
              (CountFourOf_Two,CountFiveOf_Two, 7),
              (onePct4CountFourOf_Two,onePct5CountFiveOf_Two, 8),
              (CountFourOfThree, CountFiveOfThree, 9),
              (onePct4CountFourOfThree,onePct5CountFiveOfThree, 10),
              (CountFourOfFour,CountFiveOfFour, 11),
              (onePct4CountFourOfFour,onePct5CountFiveOfFour, 12),
              (CountFourOfFive,CountFiveOfFive,13),
              (onePct4CountFourOfFive,onePct5CountFiveOfFive, 14)
            
    ) v(value1,value2, ordering)
    WHERE grouping = 1
) v
ORDER BY ordering, rn;
```

[image]

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Shorthand syntax like `*1.0` basically tells SQL Server "hey, why not just give me whatever numeric data type you want, with whatever number of decimal places you feel like." Try telling SQL Server that you want a precise type and exactly how many decimal places are important to you by applying explicit convert to `decimal(x,y)` (though it is still going to do some shifting on you depending on the inputs). But yes, agreed with the others, make a _simple_ repro. Nobody here is interested in trying to reverse engineer and troubleshoot a scrolling wall of code.

Comment: I just added the full script above in the original post. Thank you in advance!

Comment: ...but that's the problem. Surely you can reproduce the problem in a smaller, more easily reproducible example.

Comment: I tried but no luck.

Comment: Well, I [tried to reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=765aaa0a6c39eeeafc038dea48dfe57e) and couldn't. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯  I don't get the same number of rows as your screenshot and I don't get anything in the output like 0.411764 or 0.388889. This is kind of why screenshots are garbage and advised against. Maybe you could tweak that example to actually demonstrate your issue.

Comment: If CTE maps your answers to values 1 through 5 and null for the N/A case, and you only want to calculate based on the non-null cases, I think COUNT(*) may be your problem. Try COUNT(TestQ4) and COUNT(TestQ5). Those will only count non-null values. Use NULLIF to handle zero counts.

Comment: I did Count(TestQ5) and Count(TestQ4) but the last value is always wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I changed the last calculations for both questions TestQ4, and TestQ5 like this and it worked.

```
onePct4CountFourOfFive = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 5 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(TestQ4),0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your onePct5CountFiveOfFive calculation is referencing the wrong question. That looks to be the cause of your current problem.

Comment: Have to laugh so you don't cry.

Comment: @AaronBertrand. I upvoted your comment 3 times. My eyes have stopped hurting now.

Comment: I changed the last calculations for both questions TestQ4, and TestQ5 like this and it worked.  onePct4CountFourOfFive = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ4 = 5 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(TestQ4),0)